# TIFF wrong height

Tags: java, tiff

OK, I agree this is a strange question, but bear with me.

I have a `TIFF` image and I am using `Windows`. When I right-click and go to `Properties`, I see `Width = 1728 pixels` and `Height` = `1146 pixels`. When I read it with `Java` as a `BufferedImage` and call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, I see the same things. When I open it with `MS Paint`, I see the same size.

But the problem is that this size is not correct because the height is too small and the image looks **idiotic**. Now the interesting part: when I open it with `IrfanView`, I see it OK, with `Height = 2292 pixels`. When I open it with `Windows Photo Viewer`, it looks OK with `Height = 2292 pixels`.

So my question is: How did `IrfanView` and `Windows Photo Viewer` manage to recognize the correct height, although it was specified wrong in the metadata of the image? And how to do the same in Java? I don't want to show an idiotic image to the user.

P.S The image comes from outside and I can't do anything about the wrong metadata...

Comment: Lookup the TIFF format specification, then look at the exact contents of your TIFF file, and see how the height is stored in the file.

Comment: @Jesper - Thanks, I will do this.

Comment: @Jesper - Finally had the time to resolve this:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem. In fact the image was inappropriate from the beginning. The reason why `IrfanView` shows it OK, is that it compares the `Horizontal` and `Vertical` `DPI` and if they are not equal, it resizes the image to make them equal.

For example:

```
HorizontalDPI = 200
VerticalDPI = 100
Width = 800
Height = 600
```

When IrfanView opens the image it makes the following:

`Height = Height * (HorizontalDPI / VerticalDPI) = 600 * 2 = 1200`.

I ended up doing the same in my software. Everything is working fine:)

I hope this post will be useful to other people:)